# keytool md5 hash ascii?

Tags: java, android, facebook, keystore, keytool

Im having trouble to get the md5 hash (ascii) from my keystore, I just get a hex fingerprint but don't know how to get the right ascii md5 to put on facebook android app.

I just read a lot about using jdk 1.6 but I get the same result.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should post more on what you have so far, but this is the instructions I always use to get my key hash:

You should verify that ~/.android/debug.keystore exists, and that keytool and openssl is installed on your machine.

Run the following command in a terminal:

`keytool -exportcert -alias MY_ALIAS_HERE -keystore ~/path/to/my/android.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

and when prompted for the pw, type `android`.

If it still doesn't work don't worry! Our [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig) also provides another alternative by following this tutorial:

Enable debugging in our Android SDK by modifying Util.java:

private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = true;

Follow steps 6.1 to 6.3, which is mainly just making sure your app has permission to access the Internet, and SSO enabled.

Build and run the app on your phone or emulator. You should not see the permissions dialog because you did not input the application signature in your app's dashboard. Check the Android SDK debug logs via logcat (since you enabled logging in step 1), and look at your log entries for an entry with ''Android key mismatch''. This error will also provide you with the key that was sent to Facebook. Note the key's value and enter it into your Facebook app settings and make sure to save your settings.

Turn off debugging once SSO completes successfully by modifying Util.java:

private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = false;

Let me know if that helps!